# beacon detecting in foreground, background and kill (remove from background) app

Tags: swift, ibeacon, locationmanager, kontakt.io

I am working on beacon detecting in foreground, background and kill (remove from background) app.I have `kontakt` beacon.I have implemented location Manager delegate method but I can’t detect beacon in foreground and background not even called method `didEnterRegion` and  `didExitRegion` .For solution I merge location manager delegate with KTKDevicesManagerDelegate. I can’t detect beacon in location manager so I have tried  implementing in didRangeBeacons of location manager method I start `devicesManager.startDevicesDiscovery()` of KTKDeviceManagerDelegate that time detect beacon in Foreground and background ,but I can’t detect beacon when we kill app. I have already added in Info.plist NSBluetoothPeripheralUsageDescription , NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription , NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription , bluetooth-central , fetch , location.
I have added following on didFinishLaunchingWithOptions `requestAlwaysAuthorization(),requestWhenInUseAuthorization()`.

```
    //MARK:- Variable initializers
    var devicesManager: KTKDevicesManager!
    var locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    let region = CLBeaconRegion(proximityUUID: NSUUID(uuidString: "********")! as UUID, identifier: "detected")

        func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

        Kontakt.setAPIKey(“*******************”)

         self.locationManager.delegate = self
        devicesManager = KTKDevicesManager(delegate: self)
//When bluetooth Is on that time
        devicesManager.startDevicesDiscovery(withInterval: 3)

}

//MARK: - KTKDevicesManagerDelegate Method

extension AppDelegate: KTKDevicesManagerDelegate {

    func devicesManager(_ manager: KTKDevicesManager, didDiscover devices: [KTKNearbyDevice]) {

        for device in nearbyDevices {
            if let uniqueID = device.uniqueID {
                print("Detected a beacon \(uniqueID)")
            } else {
                print("Detected a beacon with an unknown unique ID")
                devicesManager.stopDevicesDiscovery()
            }
        }

    }

    func devicesManagerDidFail(toStartDiscovery manager: KTKDevicesManager, withError error: Error?) {

        print("Discovery did fail with error: \(error)")
        devicesManager.stopDevicesDiscovery()
      }

}

//MARK: - Location Manager Method

extension AppDelegate: CLLocationManagerDelegate {

    private func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didChangeAuthorizationStatus status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {
        print("STATUS CHANGED: \(status.rawValue)")
        if status == .authorizedAlways  {
            print("YAY! Authorized!")
            locationManager.startMonitoring(for: region)

        }
    }

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {

        print("update location")

        locationManager.startMonitoring(for: region)
        locationManager.startRangingBeacons(in: region)
   }



    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didStartMonitoringFor region: CLRegion) {

        print("The monitored regions are: \(manager.monitoredRegions)")
        locationManager.startMonitoring(for: region)
        locationManager.startRangingBeacons(in: region as! CLBeaconRegion)

    }

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: Error) {
        print("Location Manager failed with the following error: \(error)")
    }

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didRangeBeacons beacons: [CLBeacon], in region: CLBeaconRegion) {

       //  print("beacons : \(beacons.count)")

        devicesManager.startDevicesDiscovery()
       //So called  didDiscover method of KTKDevicesManagerDelegate method

    }

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, monitoringDidFailFor region: CLRegion?, withError error: Error) {
        print("FAIL!")
    }

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didEnterRegion region: CLRegion) {
        print("Region Entered")

        locationManager.startMonitoring(for: region)
        locationManager.startRangingBeacons(in: region as! CLBeaconRegion)

    }


    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didExitRegion region: CLRegion) {
        print("Region exited")

        locationManager.startMonitoring(for: region)
        locationManager.startRangingBeacons(in: region as! CLBeaconRegion)

    }

}
```

Comment: I don't think you can do this - you can have a look at [Conditions Under Which Bluetooth State Restoration Will Relaunch An App](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/qa/qa1962/_index.html) - assuming by "kill" you mean "force quit by the user"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must add and allow location in `NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription`.If you are in beacon region that time `didEnterRegion` method execute and out of beacon region that time `didExitRegion` method executed, that time we start and stop device discovery. we can able to detect beacon in foreground , background , lock phone and in kill state of application.

Modify your method as given below.

```
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didEnterRegion region: CLRegion) {
            print("Region Entered")
            devicesManager.startDevicesDiscovery()


        }


        func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didExitRegion region: CLRegion) {
            print("Region exited")
            devicesManager.stopDevicesDiscovery()    
        }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. You save my lots of time and finally it is working propelry. great job